# Inner join Transaction and Account Very slow

Tags: sql-server

I have a query run very slow:

```
select
    0                                              as totalAccountNew,
    0                                              as totalTransNew,
    0                                              as totalFlowNew,
    sum((t.OutAmount - t.InAmount))                as totalRevenueNew,
    dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedTime)) as datetime
from (
         select it.AccountID,
                it.CreatedTime,
                it.ServiceID,
                it.RoomID,
                it.SourceID,
                it.Amount as InAmount,
                0         as
                             OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM InputTransactions it
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = it.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID

         WHERE (s.InOut = 3 or s.InOut = 2)
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and it.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
         union all
         select ot.AccountID,
                ot.CreatedTime,
                ot.ServiceID,
                ot.RoomID,
                ot.SourceID,
                0         as InAmount,
                ot.Amount as OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM OutputTransactions ot
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = ot.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID
         WHERE s.InOut = 1
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and ot.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
     ) t
inner join Accounts a on a.AccountID = t.AccountID
where convert(varchar(10), a.CreateTime, 102) = convert(varchar(10), dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, t.CreatedTime)), 102)
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedTime))
```

It takes 9s to complete. When I comment inner join with Accounts and Where clause, then it takes 900ms.

I created a nonclustered index on AccountID in InputTransaction and OutputTransaction, created a nonclustered index in CreatedTime and CreateTime

Can you help me optimize the query? Thank you so much.

Solved:

```
select
    0                                              as totalAccountNew,
    0                                              as totalTransNew,
    0                                              as totalFlowNew,
    sum((t.OutAmount - t.InAmount))                as totalRevenueNew,
    dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedTime)) as datetime
from (
         select it.AccountID,
                it.CreatedTime,
                it.ServiceID,
                it.RoomID,
                it.SourceID,
                it.Amount as InAmount,
                0         as
                             OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM InputTransactions it
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = it.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID
                  inner join
              (select AccountID, CreateTime from Accounts
               WHERE CreateTime between :fromDate and :toDate ) as a on (a.AccountID = it.AccountID)
         WHERE (s.InOut = 3 or s.InOut = 2)
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and it.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
            and cast(a.CreateTime as date) = cast(it.CreatedTime as DATE)
         union all
         select ot.AccountID,
                ot.CreatedTime,
                ot.ServiceID,
                ot.RoomID,
                ot.SourceID,
                0         as InAmount,
                ot.Amount as OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM OutputTransactions ot
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = ot.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID
                  inner join
              (select AccountID, CreateTime from Accounts
               WHERE CreateTime between :fromDate and :toDate ) as a on (a.AccountID = ot.AccountID)
         WHERE s.InOut = 1
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and ot.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
    and cast(a.CreateTime as date) = cast(ot.CreatedTime as DATE)
     ) t
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, t.CreatedTime))
```

Comment: I solved my query based on metal suggest.
Thank metal for try to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about filter first the Accounts so you can limit results before joining?

```
select
    0                                              as totalAccountNew,
    0                                              as totalTransNew,
    0                                              as totalFlowNew,
    sum((t.OutAmount - t.InAmount))                as totalRevenueNew,
    dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedTime)) as datetime
from (
         select it.AccountID,
                it.CreatedTime,
                it.ServiceID,
                it.RoomID,
                it.SourceID,
                it.Amount as InAmount,
                0         as
                             OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM InputTransactions it
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = it.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID

         WHERE (s.InOut = 3 or s.InOut = 2)
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and it.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
         union all
         select ot.AccountID,
                ot.CreatedTime,
                ot.ServiceID,
                ot.RoomID,
                ot.SourceID,
                0         as InAmount,
                ot.Amount as OutAmount,
                s.InOut
         FROM OutputTransactions ot
                  inner join Services s on s.ServiceID = ot.ServiceID
                  inner join ServicesType st on s.ServiceType = st.ServicesTypeID
         WHERE s.InOut = 1
           and st.CategoryId = 1
           and ot.CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate
     ) t
inner join 
     (select AccountID from Accounts
            WHERE CreatedTime between :fromDate and :toDate) as a on a.AccountID = t.AccountID
WHERE convert(varchar(10), a.CreateTime, 102) = convert(varchar(10), dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, t.CreatedTime)), 102)
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedTime))
```

Comment: I did your query. It takes 6s. But it still very slow.

Comment: Omg. If I did your query and comment where clause.
It very fast 500ms
How can I optimize clause where

Comment: I"m not sure what's the purpose that where clause while you already have "between" datefrom and to

Comment: I want to a statistic with all account which created in that day

Comment: try to use "where concat(year(a.CreatedTime), month(a.CreatedTime), day(a.CreatedTime)) = concat(year(t.CreatedTime), month(t.CreatedTime), day(t.CreatedTime))"